# Is this a valid compiler optimization?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Compiler: Visual C++ 2012 RTM

Bug or not?: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763601/visual-c-2012-rtm-serious-compiler-bug

To me it seems weird it would inline calling test() into the second std::cout statement.

Comment: You should post the actual question here, instead of just linking to the issue, because links die.

Comment: The bug report seems incoherent to me. How can you tell when `test` is called?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: test() takes quite some time to complete, so I can tell when it gets called.

Comment: @NFRCR: Then the bug report is clearly bogus. The compiler is certainly free to make your code run as slow or as fast as it likes. That's purely a quality issue, not a validity issue. (It doesn't matter how the compiler does something, just what it does. If what it did is make your code slow or fast, that's clearly valid.)

Comment: As an optimization that does not modify the program output, this is within the standard. I would imagine that if `test()` had output so that this reordering would cause a difference in output, you would find it called when you expected.

Comment: Mike Dade's comment in the bug report is correct: "That's not a bug, test doesn't use or modify any global state and as a result there's no dependency between test and the first cout".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz NFRCR's question is if the compiler is allowed to move a function call forward, so that it is called between output instead of prior to it as coded.

Comment: @AnthonyBurleigh: Right, and the answer is that the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants so long as it doesn't cause certain effects the compiler is not allowed to create. (Which is what my answer below explains.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The compiler is free to make changes that are undetectable to the program. Since the `test` function has no externally-visible effects, the compiler is free to make it as early or late as it wishes, or even eliminate it entirely.

If you can explain some way this optimization made your code do something it shouldn't do, then you have something. But so far, your only claim is that it made your code run slower or faster. The compiler is free to make optimizations that make some parts of your code slower and some parts faster. In fact, that's the essence of optimization -- making performance tradeoffs that we hope will generate a net gain. That may result in poor quality generated code, though in this case it doesn't seem to, but it's most certainly valid. That's what optimization is all about.

A compiler takes your source code and produces output compiled code. It is free to build any compiled code it likes so long as it produces the observable results your source code asks it to produce. It is not required to produce the output the same way your source code does if it can find a way to produce the same effects in a way that it thinks is better. This is the whole point of optimization -- to not do literally what you asked it to do but to produce the same results some other, hopefully better, way.

Answer (score 3):

It comes down to the as-if rule. The compiler is free to transform the program any way it sees fit, so long as its external behaviour is indistinguishable from the behaviour before the transform.

A more precise formulation of the rule can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). Note that accesses to volatiles are included in this definition, hence the difference you see when changing the volatility.